# Proof of a more general correspondence theorem

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to prove the following, but I don't really know where to start...

If $\theta : G \rightarrow H$ is a surjective groupmorfism with $ker(\theta) = N$.
If we define$ S := \{U|N\leq U \leq G\}$ and $T := \{V |V\leq H\}$

Then $\theta$ and $\theta^{-1} $ induce inverse bijections between $S $ and $T$.
Even more these bijections keep inclusions, indices, normal subgroups and quotient groups.

Could anybody help me with how to prove this?

Comment: Isn't this just the usual correspondence theorem?

Comment: I tried looking for proofs of  'the correspondence theorem' and all I found was this theorem directly applied to quotient groups with the canonical projection as $\theta$...

Comment: Oh, they are the same thing. the image of the morphism $\varphi$ with kernel $N$ is isomorphic to $\frac{G}{N}$ by the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Oh okay I'll give adapting those proofs another try then, I was really under the impression that this formulation was a more general one...